# Don't fire Google Analytics in Google Tag Manager on 4 pages

Tags: google-tag-manager

I use Google Tag Manager to run Google Analytics on all pages. Now is it the case that, for technical reasons, four pages may not run Google Analytics. How can I do that?

I tried this myself by creating a page view trigger with the pages on which Google Analytics may not run. I then set this trigger as 'Exception' for the tag that Google Analytics runs on all pages. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because Google Analytics is still running on these pages. I know this because the Tag Assistant extension and the preview mode indicates that.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

[image: Google Tag Manager screenshot]

Comment: Please include the settings of the exclude trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a wild guess, since you did not include the settings for your exception trigger. But at least the image shows that your exception is a "Page view" trigger, which means that your GA tags might fire at other events (e.g. if you have click based event tracking or  similar).

I suggest you configure your exception trigger as an "custom event" trigger. Then you check the "use regex" checkbox, and enter `.*`, which means that this will fire for any GTM event. Then you set the "some custom events" option, and set a filter with the urls you want to exclude from the tracking:

[image: Exception trigger configuration]

This means that no event can trigger Google Analytics tracking on any of the urls (you have to adapt your regex accordingly). Then refresh the preview or/and publish, and this should work as expected.